# Foursquare API doesn't work when searching main categories

Tags: api, foursquare

Venues Search API has stopped working as it has been working and as it is documented.

After digging in this more deeply, it is obvious that "categoryId" parameter works only, if you define exact mach. If you define root category, it doesn't search from its subcategories as it should.

To test, you can try:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d154941735

--> Return Cuban Restaurants (4bf58dd8d48988d154941735 -> "Cuban Restaurant")

This returns 0 venues:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
(4d4b7105d754a06374d81259 is Food)

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: This is error report to Foursquare, they need to fix their service. I can see that also other developers has been seen this error lately, but here I have analysed what the problem actually is.

Comment: This might be better sent to them then. Stackoverflow is a question/answer forum, not a bug reporting forum.

Comment: This is what they say is their developer forum, but next time I'll find some other place.

BTW. Foursquare fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

add to search link additional parameter `&intent=browse`